# What caused Tup's chip to malfunction?

Tags: star-wars, the-clone-wars

In the "Order 66" arc of *Star Wars: The Clone Wars*, Tup's inhibitor chip malfunctions, causing him to begin executing Order 66 prematurely and murder a Jedi General. The malfunctioning chip is extracted and shown to be badly decayed, but no explanation is provided for what caused this to happen. At the end of the arc, Palpatine claims that a rare waterborne parasite was responsible, but he also claims that Fives was infected with the same parasite even though Fives' chip, when extracted, was perfectly intact, so he's almost certainly lying.

Is there any canon indication of what *did* cause Tup's inhibitor chip to malfunction? Or is it intended to be a riddle for the ages?

Comment: My impression is that it was simply a random malfunction, which may have had no external factor, but simply started failing perhaps due to a manufacturing defect.

Answer (score 4):

According to the evidence and the context within the episode, it seems to have been a tumor growing in his head around the chip. The cause of this tumor is not specified, but we do know that this is the cause of the malfunction of the chip. I've watched that episode numerous times, trying to find any evidence in the Aurebesh lettering on the computer screens and other possible clues, but I still cannot find a cause for the tumor. As you stated, it appears to be a "riddle for the ages."

Comment: I was under the impression that the chip itself *was* the tumour, i.e. there wasn't actually a tumour, just the chip.

Comment: You could improve this answer if you could provide a direct quote from the episode instead of paraphrasing it.